# how to get list data from associative model in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

below is my query

```
$students_idsss = $this->Purchase->find('list', array(
            'fields'=>array('Student.id','Student.first_name'),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Purchase.publisher_id' => $publisherID
            ),
            'group'=>'student_id'
                )
        );
```

i am getting error : QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Student.first_name' in 'field list'

Comment: You can use `Hash::combine` after fetching results. Model `list` method is only compatible with same model. You can not use with associated models.

Comment: Hash::combine is working fine!  Thanks bro.